# Having an error with grid_forget() where it cant find the attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

Im doing a small project using tkinter to have a window that has a changing middle frame

```
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()


    def input_data():
      personal_data_frame.grid_forget()
      input_data_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, weight=0)
      input_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSWE", weight=1)

    def personal_data():
      personal_data_frame = ttk.Frame(root, weight=1)
      personal_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
    personal_data()
    input_data()
```

So with this for me it can not seem to remove the personal data frame (I have some widgets in the frame I just took them out for simplicity)

The error I get is "AttributeError: object has no attribute grid_forget"
I am almost completely new to tkinter in general but I don't plan on giving up

Comment: always add tag `python` and then code will be highlighted.

Comment: `personal_data_frame` is local variable created in `personal_data` so it doesn't exists in other functions. You should get different error. You have to use `global personal_data_frame` inside `personal_data` to assign `Frame` to global variable and then it can be used in other functions.

Comment: `Frame` doesn't have option `weight`. Create minimal working code which has problem only with `object has no attribute grid_forget`.

Comment: Thanks for the information about weight aswell

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many mistakes and it doesn't gives error `AttributeError: object has no attribute grid_forget`

My example has no problem with removing `Frame`. It assigns `Frame` to global variable and then other function has access to this `Frame` and it can remove it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def input_data():
    personal_data_frame.grid_forget()
    input_data_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root)#, weight=0) # ERROR
    input_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSWE")#, weight=1) # ERROR

def personal_data():
    global personal_data_frame

    personal_data_frame = ttk.Frame(root)#, weight=1) # ERROR
    personal_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
personal_data()
input_data()
root.mainloop()
```

---

You may have problem `AttributeError: object has no attribute grid_forget` if you assign something different then tkinter's widget to `personal_data_frame` - ie. string,  `object()`, etc.

This code shows error `AttributeError: object has no attribute grid_forget` because I assign `object()` to `personal_data_frame` after `personal_data()` and `object()` doesn't have method `grid_forget()`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def input_data():
    personal_data_frame.grid_forget()
    input_data_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root)#, weight=0) # ERROR
    input_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSWE")#, weight=1) # ERROR

def personal_data():
    global personal_data_frame

    personal_data_frame = ttk.Frame(root)#, weight=1) # ERROR
    personal_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)


root = tk.Tk()
personal_data()
personal_data_frame = object()
input_data()
root.mainloop()
```